# Create a new column which shows if a customer has booked before

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a column (BookedBefore?) which identifies if a new enquiry made is by a customer that has booked before.

```
Enquirydate Booked  CustomerID  BookedBefore?
5/19/2018   TRUE    598         NO
8/2/2018    FALSE   598         Yes
9/20/2018   FALSE   598         Yes
1/13/2019   FALSE   598         NO
7/26/2018   FALSE   611         NO
9/30/2017   FALSE   640         NO
5/2/2017    FALSE   732         NO
10/4/2017   FALSE   732         NO
8/25/2017   FALSE   766         NO
2/3/2018    FALSE   773         NO
5/2/2018    TRUE    773         YES
1/27/2019   FALSE   773         YES
5/26/2019   FALSE   972         NO
6/22/2019   FALSE   1022        NO
4/27/2019   FALSE   1024        NO
5/5/2017    FALSE   1148        NO
4/25/2019   FALSE   1323        NO
3/24/2019   FALSE   1354        NO
10/31/2018  TRUE    1596        NO
8/6/2017    FALSE   1623        NO
8/8/2018    FALSE   1623        NO
3/12/2019   TRUE    1623        NO
3/13/2019   FALSE   1623        YES
```

CustomerID 598 booked(TRUE) on 5/19/2018. For every future enquiry, this customer made should be labelled as YES for "BookedBefore?" as shown. CustomerID 598 made an enquiry on 8/2/2018, this should be labelled as Yes for "BookedBefore?"

Some help will be appreciated. Thank you.

I am using google BigQuery to carry out this task.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I have the columns EnquiryDate, Booked and CustomerID. I am trying to create a new column BookedBefore? based on these three columns.

Comment: You should be careful storing such data, depending on other table data. Either create a view, or use triggers or computed column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query checks to see if a user has at least one prior booking (their first), and then joins it to the original table and compares to see if a prior booking exists.

```
with first_booking as (
  select CustomerID, min(Enquirydate) as first_booking_date from <dataset>.<table> where Booked = TRUE group by 1
)
select
  a.Enquirydate,
  a.Booked,
  a.CustomerID,
  case when b.first_booking_date is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as has_booked_before
from <dataset>.<table> a
left join first_booking b on a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID and b.first_booking_date < a.Enquirydate
```

Comment: Thank you! just what I needed.